# Getting the following error "Failed: unknown error: a.tagName.toUpperCase is not a function"

Tags: javascript, protractor

When i tried to enter text into a text box, I'm getting the error. I can able to click, but unable to enter any text into text box using Send Keys. I also tried with Javascript executor

```
<input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" id="propertyName" maxlength="50" name="propertyName" required="" type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]*">
```

I tried the following codes,

```
element(by.xpath("//input[@name='propertyName']")).sendKeys('tex');
browser.executeScript("element(by.css('#propertyName')).setAttribute('value', 'text')"); 
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '" +" inputText "+"')", addMetaData.txtBoxKey);
```

I tried the below actions, it shows browser.actions.click is not a function,

```
browser.actions.click(addMetaData.txtBoxKey).sendKeys('text').perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

i have missed the parenthesis for actions and now its working fine,

```
browser.actions().click(addMetaData.txtBoxKey).sendKeys('text').perform();
```

But still, wonder why SendKeys doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:-

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '" +" inputText "+"')", addMetaData.txtBoxKey.getWebElement());
```